# Why are values of type () inspected?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, the `()` type has two values, namely, `()` and bottom. If you have an expression `e :: ()`, there's no point in actually inspecting it, since either it's `e = ()` or by inspecting it you're crashing a program which could otherwise have not crashed.

Hence, I figured that perhaps operations on values of type `()` would not inspect the value and would not distinguish between `()` and bottom.

However, this is wildly untrue:

```
▎λ ghci
GHCi, version 9.0.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> u = (undefined :: ())
ghci> show u
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:75:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:1:6 in interactive:Ghci1
ghci> () == u
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:75:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:1:6 in interactive:Ghci1
ghci> f () = "ok"
ghci> f u
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:75:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:1:6 in interactive:Ghci1
```

What is the reason for this? Here are some conjectures:

1. For some reason that I can't think of, it's useful to be non-lazy on `()`. Sometimes we want that bottom to propagate.
2. Haskell semantics are written in such a way that destructuring *any* ADTs, even trivial ones, inspects them. This means that having `case (undefined :: ()) of { () -> ... }` *not* throw would be a violation of language semantics
3. `()` is an extremely special case and simply isn't worth the attention to eke out this tiny extra bit of safety in a massive language like Haskell
4. There's also the possible combination explanation of 2+3, that Haskell *could* have had semantics dictating that an expression `case e of` inspects `e` *unless* it is of type `()`, but that would pollute the language spec for relatively low benefit

Comment: I would call it “weird inconsistency”, not “extra safety”. Changing the number of variants in ways that look like they should preserve behaviour could change whether a program terminates or whether it produces an error?

Comment: I call it "extra safety" because in (almost?) every situation, avoidance of an optional bottom is desirable. Sometimes extra bottoms mean better performance (ala BangPatterns), but that's not true in this case afaik

Comment: Avoiding it by making it impossible is great, but avoiding it by ignoring the error conditions that led to it is the opposite of safe.

Comment: ie, a bottom of type `()` is almost always indicative of a programmer error, so to not inspect it would be to violate "fail fast"? Interesting point

Comment: Yes.  "or by inspecting it you're crashing a program which could otherwise have not crashed." I would prefer for my programs to crash if there is cause for them to crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will address this part:

> For some reason that I can't think of, it's useful to be non-lazy on `()`. Sometimes we want that bottom to propagate.

Let's have a look at [`Control.Parallel.Strategies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-1.1.0.1/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html) (version 1, an older version). This is a module for parallel evaluation. Let's focus on one of its functions for the sake of simplicity:

```
parMap :: Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The result of `parMap strat f xs` is the same as `map f xs`, except that the list is computed in parallel. What is the `strat` argument? Well,

```
strat :: Strategy b
```

means

```
strat :: b -> ()
```

There are only two things you can do with `strat`:

- call it and ignore the result, which by laziness amounts to not calling it at all;
- call it and *force* the result, even if you know it's `()` or a bottom.

`parMap` does the latter, in parallel. This allows the caller to specify a `strat` argument that evaluates the list values of type `b` *as needed*. For example

```
parMap (\(x,y) -> ()) f xs
parMap (\(x,y) -> x `seq` ()) f xs
parMap (\(x,y) -> x `seq` y `seq` ()) f xs
```

are valid calls, and will cause `parMap` to evaluate the new list-of-pairs only to expose the pair constructor, also the first component, also the second component, respectively.

Hence, forcing the `()` result of `strat` in this case allows the user to control how much evaluation to perform during `parMap`, i.e. how much to force the result (in parallel), and consequently which parts of the result should be left unevaluated. (By comparison `map f xs` would leave the result fully unevaluated -- it is completely lazy. `parMap` can not do that otherwise it is not longer parallel.)

---

Minor digression: note that the GADT

```
data a :~: b where
    Refl :: t :~: t
```

has one constructor like `()`. Here, it is mandatory that such values are forced as in:

```
foo :: Int :~: String -> Int -> String
foo Refl x = x ++ " hello"
```

Here the first argument must be a bottom. By forcing that, we make the function error out with an exception. If we did not force that, we would get a very nasty undefined behavior like those in C and C++, completely breaking type safety. Haskell will correctly reject any attempt to circumvent that:

```
foo :: Int :~: String -> Int -> String
foo _ x = x ++ " hello"
```

triggers a type error at compile time.

Comment: In other words, my assumption that "more laziness on types `t ~ ()` is better" is just plain wrong. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect it's none of the things you said. Instead, this is so that the language is predictable and consistent.

There are, essentially, two things you observed, and I consider them to be separate things. The first is that checking whether a `x` is indeed `()` with a `case` statement forces evaluation of `x`; the second is that the instances (of `Show` and `Eq`) are written to use a `case` statement.

- Pattern matching: the predictable, consistent rule here is that if you write `case <e0> of <pat> -> <e1>`, then `e0` is evaluated far enough to check whether the constructors in `pat` are in fact in the given places. Well, okay, there's some wrinkles here to do with irrefutable patterns; let's say instead that `e0` is evaluated far enough to check whether `pat` actually does match! For the `()` type, that means that the pattern `()` causes full evaluation -- because you've specified the full value that you expect it to be -- while the pattern `x` or `_` can match without further evaluation.
- Class instances: the natural inductive way to specify what the various class instances do is to always have an outermost `case` that matches against each available constructor with simple variable patterns for the fields, then does something (presumably recursive calls) on each of the fields in turn. That is, simplifying a bit, the `show` implementation goes like:

  ```
  show x = case x of
      <Con0> field00 field01 field02 <...> -> "<Con0>"
          ++ " " ++ show field00
          ++ " " ++ show field01
          ++ " " ++ show field02
          ++ <...>
      <Con1> field10 field11 field12 <...> -> "<Con1>"
          ++ " " ++ show field10
          ++ " " ++ show field11
          ++ " " ++ show field12
          ++ <...>
      <...>
  ```

  It is very natural for the specialization of this scheme to the single-constructor, zero-field type `()` to go:

  ```
  show x = case x of
      () -> "()"
  ```

  (Additionally, the Report specifies that `(==)` is is always strict in both arguments; but that property would also arise naturally from the obvious way of writing a generic `Eq` instance derivation algorithm.) Therefore the path of least surprise is for class instances to pattern match on their argument(s).

Comment: Is this different from #2?

Comment: @FrownyFrog I think my first bullet point is related to #2, yes, but it's more of an exploration of why that's a good choice rather than a flat statement of how the language works. (And I think my second bullet point is not related to #2.)

Comment: I've chosen to accept the other answer because it gives concrete examples of why this kind of regularity is, indeed, useful in the real world. However, I want to acknowledge that this is a really nice answer and the really the two complement each other!

Answer (score 1):

#2 is definitely true.

The `()` type is just a nullary `data` type with special type/data constructor syntax:

```
 data () = ()
```

As a result, the Haskell 2010 report, while only providing an informal semantics, makes it pretty clear in section *3.17.2 Informal Semantics of Pattern Matching* that the expression:

```
case undefined of () -> "ack!"
```

will be evaluated as per rule #5:

> Matching the pattern `con pat1 … patn` against a value, where `con` is a constructor defined by `data`, depends on the value:
>
> - If the value is of the form `con v1 … vn`, sub-patterns are matched left-to-right against the components of the data value; if all matches succeed, the overall match succeeds; the first to fail or diverge causes the overall match to fail or diverge, respectively.
> - If the value is of the form `con′ v1 … vm`, where `con` is a different constructor to `con′`, the match fails.
> - If the value is ⊥, the match diverges.

Here, the value of `undefined` is ⊥, so the third bullet point applies, and the match diverges.  And if the match diverges, the program diverges, and if the program diverges it must terminate with an error or -- at worst -- loop forever.  It cannot continue as if nothing has happened.  Admittedly, this last part is not explicitly stated, but it is the only reasonable interpretation for the semantics of a divergent evaluation of an expression.